# MySql Query Building help needed

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

**users table**

| id | name | company_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user 1 | 1 |
| 2 | user 2 | 2 |
| 3 | user 3 | 1 |

How can I select all the company_id uniquely while ordering them by user name ?

I have tried below query in `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` false mode

```
select
  distinct `company_id`
from
  `users`
order by
  `name` DESC
```

But this messed up my ordering.

Comment: Can you include the exact output you want here?

Comment: the output would be company id 1, 2

Comment: @DipuAhmed If the company has multiple names then which name do you want to chose when ordering? i.e. For Company 1 in your example, should you be ordering by `user 1` or `user 3`?

Comment: that would be user 3 since this is the one that come first if i order them by descending order and it has company id 1

Comment: You'd probably need an aggregate then, e.g. `SELECT company_id FROM users GROUP BY company_id ORDER BY MAX(name) DESC`, or if you wanted ascending order `ORDER BY MIN(name) ASC`

Comment: @GarethD I like the way you think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So based on your requirements you'd need to do something like:

```
select `company_id`
from
  `users`
group by `company_id`
order by MAX(`name`) DESC
```

This should group company ids and order them based on the descending order of the last name that appears in that group.